# substitute for vector push_back for better performance

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, buffer

I have a code in c++ in visual studio, that acquires data from a machine and does some graphical rendering ( using opengl) in real time.I have made some modification in the code to store all the data coming from machine to a memory buffer  ( a vector of floating point numbers ) apart from the graphical rendering ,  till the time the machine operates and copies the contents of the buffer to a text file when the machine stop operating.I am using push_back command to fill the vector and real time rendering has started showing a lag of few seconds.I am aware of the fact that this lag comes of the performance hit by the vector push_back.I was looking for a possible substitute ( using and array or using paged memory ) to make to rendering real time again.My trouble in using array is , the size of the array couldn't be defined before the machine operation.The time which machine run is not predetermined.And i would like to keep the whole data in the memory buffer till the end of machine operation.Does any one have any suggestion to remove the performance hit.

Comment: the alternative is to use `vector::resize` to make the vector the size you want, then use `vector[i] = x` instead of `vector.push_back(x)`

Comment: Even if you don't know the precise size required, can you at least *guess* at the size? This is the only way to minimize reallocations. You can make it too large, you'll just require more memory—a classic trade-off.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any command  that i can put inside a vector Reserve() function that corresponds to the all available memory in the RAM, so that i dont have to specify the size of vector in Reserve.The vector will be saving millions of floating point numbers ?

Comment: @sarath you want to use `max_size()` method. It will give you the largest possible size of the vector. [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: You're not likely to be successful allocating max_size(). And if you were to grab all available memory (which is not what max_size does), you are likely to cause instability in your program and o/s (unless you can guarantee you are the only process active during this period). @CodyGray gave the best advice -- you should make an educated guess as to max size and call resize().

Answer (score 1):

From easiest to hardest, which coincidentally is also from biggest impact to smallest.

## Preallocate the vector

One of the slowest parts of using a vector is the "copying" when you get above the maximum size of the array. If you know the size of the vector, than the best way to speed up adding elements to the array is to preallocate.

There are two ways to do this. The first is to use `vector::resize`, which will expand the array and initialize all the values to the default value (usually, read on). This can be great if you want to make a full array of the default value (like 0). However, if you don't want to set the default value (initializing to default can be expensive, or the default object could be an error state), you should use `vector::reserve`. `vector::reserve` allocates the space for all the new elements. In my experience, vector::reserve is better for classes, vector::resize is better for POD.

## In C++11, move instead of copy

If you have POD stuff, than this won't help you. But if you have say, a vector of vectors, than moving can be much more efficient than copying. `vector.push_back(std::move(x))` will steal the resources from x. If your class cannot have a default move constuctor, write one before putting it in a vector.

## Make your own allocator

You can create your own http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator that doesn't initialize on resize. Of course, this usually doesn't help.